# jquery returning empty unless selector is preceeded with the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Using jQuery I am trying to select an element that has a unique id. I need to check the length of the returned jquery object to see if the element is there on the page.

if i write:

```
$('#main-content').length
```

i get 0. Strangely, the element is there. Instead, if i write:

```
$('main#main-content').length
```

i am getting 1.

I thought i need not specify the element before the selector. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: can you paste the markup here?

Comment: `div.#main-content` that would suggest a div with a **class** `#main-content`

Comment: Please show us your `HTML`. It seems like you have an element that looks like this: `<div class="#main-content">...</div>`, which would just be wrong.

Comment: actually, that totally invalid selector should produce an error `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div.#main-content`

Comment: sorry guys...the . is not there. it's a typo. But the problem is valid. I am editing the question.

Comment: Can you still post your HTML? How many elements with `id="main-content"` do you have?

Comment: well, that makes no sense at all - the problem is not reproducible ... can you reproduce it?

Comment: what happened to the div? (still not reproducible) - please try to write some HTML that accurately reproduces this non-reproducible issue

Comment: @Kiranramchandran: It's a huge div. I am giving just the opening here:

`<main id="main-content" role="main" class="g-tools-area fixed-wrap">`

Comment: that's not a `div` - that's a `main` - what browser? and what version of jQueery

Comment: Make sure the id is not part of an iframe and that you dont have 2 elements with that same id.

Comment: @CataJohn: yes, it's part of an iframe. Can you please explain why that does not work !!

Comment: @YeasirArafatMajumder the iframe is basically a separate document so you wont be able to find elements inside of it by globally looking for them. You have to search the iframe itself so `$('#your-iframe-id #main-content)` should work

Comment: @CataJohn: Even that does not work. My iframe has an id of **content-frame**. So i tried `$('#content-frame #main-content')`. still comes out empty. Only $('main#main-content') works.

Comment: @YeasirArafatMajumder that wont work indeed. Sorry. I will provide an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An iframe is basically a separate document from the parent. So searching the parent will not find elements from the iframe.

However, this should work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var iFrameEl = $("iframe#frameID").contents();
    iFrameEl.find("#main-content").addClass('test');
});
```